# How to fix this error in Lambda function for Listing SNS subscriptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Im trying to list the SNS topic subscriptions through a Lambda function in python and running in to an Indentation error

AWS CLI command works fine, While Lambda function is throwing the error

```
import boto3
sns = boto3.client('sns') 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
response = event(sns.list_subscriptions)
print (response())
```

Expected: List of all subscriptions for all topics

Actual Result:

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function'"
}

Request ID:
"82aa7f11-ad9d-4e80-aadb-838a22b361f7"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 82aa7f11-ad9d-4e80-aadb-838a22b361f7 Version: $LATEST
Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': expected an indented block (lambda_function.py, line 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is simply how you formatting the question, but the error is basically saying that you need to indent the lines that define the function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = event(sns.list_subscriptions)
    print (response())
```

Python is very specific about indentation since it defines how blocks of code are executed.